# Как такое возможно?

Tags: android, java

```
Log.v("math",1600/6000*4500+"");
```

В логе:

```
08-12 10:28:33.563  26473-26473/dlp.tmea.gold V/math﹕ 0
```

Либо я, либо андроид сошёл с ума.

Comment: "Я сошла с ума... Какая досада" (C) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Операция производится с типом int.

1600 / 6000 = 0, 0 * 4500 = 0.

Нужно переписать на 1600f/6000*4500.

Answer (score 3):

1600/6000 = 0, так как считается как целочисленные, то есть он считается переменные и результат вычисления как int. Надо явно тип указать, если хотите float получить.

напишите:

```
Log.v("math",1600F/6000*4500+"");
```